# UIToolkit for Android and Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gui-toolkit

I am making a GUI for my android game project on Unity using the UIToolkit. 
The Sample Scenes (eg Kitchen Sink) works fine on the Unity Editor.
But when I run the exact same sample scenes on the android device , it doesnt work. 
The Button Texture is slightly shifted from the actual Touch Region.
I have tried different Android Devices, but the result is the same.

I tried accessing the Sprite Locations using a function like

```
public float getYpos(this IPositionable sprite )
{
    if(sprite == null)
        return ;
    float toRet = sprite.position.y;
    return toRet;
}
```

But it the code returns an no Value!

I even tried using the "IPositionablePositioningExtensions" and returning the Sprite location. But no Success. Although I am not sure how to use the 'IPositionablePositioningExtensions', I have just started a beginner in this field.

My Button Creation Looks something like this :

```
    playButton = UIButton.create("playUp.png", "playDown.png",0,0);
    playButton.positionCenter();
    playButton.scale = new Vector3(0.4f,0.4f,0);
```

Here is a screenshot of how the sample scene looks on an android device.
The Bounding box is the region where the Touch Works, while the Button texture is being rendered somewhere else.

[image]

The Button texture should have been in the center position, although it moves to some other position while the touch region remains where it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
The onAwake method returns a different screen size than the actual screen size.

So added the following code to the uiCamera in ui.cs file

```
public static void setSize()
    {
        _uiCamera.orthographicSize = Screen.height / 2;
        // Set the camera position based on the screenResolution/orientation
        _uiCamera.transform.position = new Vector3( Screen.width / 2, -Screen.height / 2, -10.0f ); 
    }
```

This is called once the screen has been set up.

Answer (score 0):

From the guide on the develoeper's site:
(...)
Do not try to create your UI in Awake as the UI script may not be done initializing yet. Use Start instead.

edit: I thought you were creating ui in the awake method, but i tried myself and I have the same problem of yours even if I create it in the start method as suggested in the guide. Now I will test your solution. In fact If i change scene and reload the UI scene without restarting the application everything works right.

Comment: Just add the above code in UI.cs and then call it once from the update() of UI.CS , or call it every time the screen/scene is created.

Comment: I figured it out anyway but many thanks for the answer kyuubi!